# Storefront solutions for dynamically generated digital content?

Tags: web-applications, web-frameworks, online-store, pre-packaged

I'm looking for the cheapest options available for offering dynamically-generated digital content (a la Carfax.com or those credit report ripoff sites).  Paypal would be fine for the payment gateway, but I'm interested in avoiding from-scratch coding for the storefront application.  Obviously the content variable capture pages and content generation module would have to be custom work, but the other pieces are rather generic.

Know of any pre-packaged themable/skinnable app including Account Management (logins/forgot password/update account), "My Purchased Content", internal management tools, etc?  .Net technology /preferred/.  Hosted vs. installed doesn't matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own company did some research on this previously and found that [aspdotnetstorefront.com](http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com) was a pretty good out of the box solution that can be either hosted with them or on your own server (for a price) and can be themed/skinned.

We decided to roll our own in the end just due to the fact that we knew clients would be wanting changes that the store software didn't include - and we were right - but it does what 95% of people will want from an online store, doesn't cost the earth and comes with PayPal integration (and a bunch of other payment portals) out of the box.

Might be worth a look to see if it suits your needs. It might be overkill for what you want but hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I took a look but I'm not finding any text related to digital downloads, only shipped products.  Can you elaborate on this solution as it relates to digital content?  Thanks.

Comment: Ah! I misread the question. Sorry about that. I contacted aspdotnetstorefront and they don't have digital downloads out of the box but it can be added into their existing setup just like any online store. I previously did an online store that used TryMedia to packaged digital downloads which was integrated into a standard storefront. So you would DRM your movies/games/whatever and upload to TryMedia servers and then integrate using your own code on your store. They were easy to use but pricey because you pay for bandwidth, the DRM, etc. Take a look over at TryMedia.com